# Bajaj pulsar 150 cc doesn't start

Tags: motorcycle, starting, bajaj

I tried to start my bajaj pulsar after a 500 km ride but it doesn't start even with kick start and also self start. I saw battery symbol blinking for a while, could it be a battery issue?

Comment: yes, it can be a battery issue. When was the last time you drove your bike and when was the last time you have changed your battery? Also, is there any power at all? What happens when you press on inginition? Nothing at all or maybe some sound? Does your electronics come on (i.e. is there any power at all?)

Comment: Yes there is power that lights up the dashboard and sound comes up when I press on ignition but engine doesn't start (even with kick start). It started all fine during the 260 km trip  I had yesterday except for some starting issues during the later half. I came home and left the bike to rest for 4 hours and the bike doesn't start at all.

Comment: Have you checked the spark plugs?